# Apache Beam using Spark Runner Deployment on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: apache-spark, cloud-foundry, apache-beam

I have a requirement to deploy a Apache Beam application using Spark Runtime engine. My Question is if I can deploy a Spark Application on Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment. Could you please provide examples if available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  Cloud Foundry can run Apache Spark applications. CF now has the ability to mount persistent volumes, manage container networking for the Spark cluster itself, and provide isolation segments for different kind of compute nodes (e.g. to identify a sub-cluster with high performance networking that might be more suited to Spark apps vs. general purpose apps).

You still need a backing store outside of CF for the data you want to feed into Spark or output from Spark. This could be HDFS, Cassandra, JDBC/SQL, NFS, HTTP / S3 , etc.

Cloud Foundry is stateless, but it’s quite capable of running workloads like Spring Cloud Data Flow today, which integrates with Apache Spark quite nicely, along with Hbase, Hadoop, regular RDBMSs, Kafka/Redis/RabbitMQ, FTP servers, cloud services.. whatever you need really.

Here are the links, you can refer them.

[How to leverage Pivotal Cloud Foundry, Pivotal HD, Apache Spark and EMC ECS to analyze Twitter data](http://www.recorditblog.com/post/how-to-leverage-pivotal-cloud-foundry-pivotal-hd-apache-spark-and-emc-ecs-to-analyze-twitter-data/)

[Spark on Cloud Foundry](https://gist.github.com/Amit-PivotalLabs/7c86c92aae3123ac809e81795a41acfa)